# How to do virtual networking (all types) in virt-manager?

Tags: virt-manager

Surprisingly, there is no documentation on the official site http://virt-manager.org/
I specifically need documentation on bridged / host-only / NAT virtual networking via the GUI.

Comment: What sort of documentation ? virt-manager is a graphical tool. RHEL has some, see also libirt. It would help if you have a specific question with a specific step.

Comment: Like I said, I specifically need documentation on bridged / host-only virtual networking via the GUI. virt-manager has two tabs to configure networking; that confuses me. Tabs are 'Virtual Networks' and 'Network Interfaces' and can be accessed by right clicking 'localhost (QEMU)' and choosing 'details' Hope this is specific enough.

Comment: See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Virtualized_guest_installation_overview-Creating_guests_with_virt_manager.html - I aslo suggest you read the documentation on qemu and libvirt https://libvirt.org/docs.html kvm (and to some extent vbox) are built on qemu and virt-manager is a graphical front end for libvirt.

Comment: Network interfaces configure the vitrual network hardware and vitrual networks is how the virtual machine connects to your network (NAT, private network, bridge).

Comment: Well, I'd like to configure 'Bridged Networking' with my NIC card, as I did in Virtualbox. Should I use 'Virtual Networks' or 'Network INterfaces'?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on your version of virt manager

In your guest, select host networking

[image]

If your version of virt manager does not automatically add a bridge you need to manually configure your bridge.

https://web.archive.org/web/20190831062148/http://blog.bodhizazen.com:80/linux/virt-manager-bridged-networking

https://web.archive.org/web/20190803104448/http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/bridge-wireless-cards/