# How can I configure network access to vm instance using virt-manager?

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge, virt-manager

I use QEMU/KVM as virtualization solution and `virt-manager` UI to configure the VM instances. I share a LAN network behind a Cisco router (192.168.1.1) to which multiple windows machines connect and also my Ubuntu (16.04) Linux server. The Linux server runs kvm and a windows 10 VM instance.

My question is:

How can I set up the network on the Linux server so that the VM instance is on the exact same network and subnet as the host and also on the same network as all other machines that connect to the LAN, handed out by my Cisco router. The router runs a DHCP server so I do not want kvm to run its own DHCP server because as of now my VM instance is getting an IP on a different network segment.

The goal is to have the VM instance accessible from any other machine on my LAN network.

Can someone please share in detail how I can either set this up via `virt-manager` or else manually with specific instructions in order to configure the network as described above.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/551680/how-to-do-virtual-networking-all-types-in-virt-manager, first answer (you need a bridged network). So select "host network" in the network configuration of your guest.